# How to listen to multiple urls with Diet.js?

Tags: node.js, diet-js

The documentation for Diet.js demonstrates a basic web server as:

```js
var server = require('diet');
var app = server();

app.listen('http://localhost:8000');

app.get('/', function ($) {
  $.end('Hello World!');
});
```

The above code snippet only listens to *localhost* on port *8000*. However, If I would want the server to listen to requests with domain as *localhost* as well as the *ip-address* (and probably even the machine name), is there a way to do it? I think there isn't, at least as per the developer's documentation but it would be great if someone could point to me a decent hack of some sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change:

```
app.listen('http://localhost:8000');
```

to:

```
app.listen(8000);
```

or:

```
app.listen('http://0.0.0.0:8000/');
```

Comment: Why did I not try this earlier? Thank you!